# Get ListView HiddenField value via Request.Form.Keys using MasterPages ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, master-pages

This code works without using a masterpage. However I need it to work using masterpage. I have placed a HiddenField control and a LinkButton control in a ListView...

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" postbackurl="orderhistorydetail.aspx">View</asp:LinkButton>
```

Now I need to retrieve the value(s) from the server side. Again, this code works without using masterpage...

```
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            s.AppendLine(key + ": " + Request.Form[key]);
        }
        string formData = s.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(formData);
```

How can I use this code when using a masterpage?

Comment: The result of `System...WriteLine(formData);` is empty?

Comment: Did the hiddenfield in html rendered normally? your code seems fine.

Comment: System...WriteLine(formData); is empty when using this code with masterpage content page. It works when I don't use masterpage content page. I need to use this on a masterpage content page.